# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-0094 caught when using quartz

Tags: oracle, exception, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler and now set jobstore to jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
I use the same database to store my own data in this project and it works well including create new tables from code.
Now the quartz part give

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1044)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3317)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3362)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:92)
```

I am pretty new to quartz, could anyone please give me some hint?
Should I create quartz tables by myself?
I didn't see any information about creating tables for quartz.

Thank you and happy new year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . You must first create the database tables for Quartz to use . Such scripts are in the `docs/dbTables` directory of the Quartz distribution.

See [this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09) for more information